org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
I got this project from GitHub and encountered an issue when I tried to run it. The problem seems to be related to the AuthenticationManager.
The complete error message is:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' defined in class
path resource [com/example/demo/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]:
Failed to instantiate
[org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]:
Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception with
message: null

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/api/all", "/api/auth/**", "/oauth2/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagementCustomizer -> sessionManagementCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.disable())
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exp -> exp.authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()))

                .oauth2Login(oAuthConfig -> oAuthConfig.authorizationEndpoint(authEndPoint -> authEndPoint.authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository()))
                                                       .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.oidcUserService(customOidcUserService).userService(customOAuth2UserService))
                                                       .tokenEndpoint(token -> token.accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient()))
                                                       .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                                                       .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler));

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}

the pom.xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

contrller:
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@jakarta.validation.Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication);
        LocalUser localUser = (LocalUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt, GeneralUtils.buildUserInfo(localUser)));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        try {
            userService.registerNewUser(signUpRequest);
        } catch (UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException e) {
            log.error("Exception Ocurred", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse(false, "Email Address already in use!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"));
    }
}


Please share the compete stacktrace

It seems that you picked a pretty bad starting point. Don't trust a project with disabled protection against CSRF in a filter-chain with oauth2Login. Don't trust a project with custom Token based authentication filter, Spring Security provides with extended (and safe) support for resource servers already. Don't trust a project with more than one request authorization in a single filter-chain (oauth2Login relies on session cookies, not on Bearer tokens).

Also, you seem to be willing to authenticate users on a resource server (a REST API with Bearer-based security) and to then send a JWT to single-page or mobile frontends. You should be doing neither of the two. Users should be authenticated on an authorization server (not on a resource server), and requests should be authorized with sessions cookies between the user device and your backend (tokens should not leave the server and be used only for inter-service calls).

@ch4mp Thanks for your comment and advice, the main reason I used this project was because I needed a social login page form like google, facebook .. I searched a lot but I don't find a good solution, What the best practice for that please?

Use an OIDC Provider, most include social login. You have a choice of many solutions either on-premise like Keycloak and Spring Authorization Server (but the latter probably requires a better knowledge of the OAuth2 & OIDC specs than you have), or in the cloud (like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, ...). Then learn about the OAuth2 BFF pattern.

@ch4mp Thanks a lot :), coz it seems hard to build a social login form from scratch and like you say above the projects form internet not secure enoguh

The problem was due to new changes in Spring Security
I changed this code
@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManagerBean();
}

to this
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

and change name of the method
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { ... }

to
 protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { .. }

